# Crontab runs /etc/init.d/ scripts but won't run service restart?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql, cron

I'm writing a script to restart mysql and send me an email whenever it goes down. I'm using crontab to run the script every x minutes.

I'm having an issue with the script using service commands.

```
service mysql restart
```

Does not seem to work, however,

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Does work fine. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu !  If you must insist, we'll _bear_ with you, but what you suggest is something entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in your terminal

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

I think thats what your looking for